# sqlite3_open - 'Database Failed to open'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, sqlite

I'm new to iOS programming.
I don't know what is the cause of my error.
My code simply load the database when the app is starting but it force closes itself whenever I'm running it.

Here is my **header file**:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  Manicuriousv2
//
//  Created by Bonafide on 6/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Bonafide_iOSTeam. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    sqlite3 *AppDB;

}
- (IBAction)btnAvailPop:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnRstPop:(id)sender;
- (NSString *) filePath;
- (void) openDB;

- (void)
createTable: (NSString *) Ref_ServType
withfield1: (NSString *) ServID
withfield2: (NSString *) ServiceTitle;


@end
```

**Implementation file:**

```
   //
//  ViewController.m
//  Manicuriousv2
//
//  Created by Bonafide on 6/5/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Bonafide_iOSTeam. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)
createTable: (NSString *) Ref_ServType
withfield1: (NSString *) ServID
withfield2: (NSString *) ServiceTitle;


{
}

    -(NSString *) filePath{
    NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ManicuriousDB.db"
            ];

}

-(void) openDB{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &AppDB) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(AppDB);
        NSAssert(0,@"Database Failed to open");
    }else{

        NSLog(@"Database Opened!");
    }
    }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self openDB];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnAvailPop:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Avail List"
    message:@"Are you sure you want to avail the services you have selected?"
    delegate:nil
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"Avail", nil];

    [alert show];


}

- (IBAction)btnRstPop:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
    initWithTitle:@"Avail List"
    message:@"Are you sure you want to reset the list of services you have selected?"
    delegate:nil
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"Reset", nil];

    [alert show];

}
@end
```

**Error Message:**

```
2014-06-06 16:43:28.502 Manicuriousv2[2261:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x99341f0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-06-06 16:43:28.590 Manicuriousv2[2261:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[ViewController openDB], /Users/jennifer/Desktop/Manicuriousv2/Manicuriousv2/ViewController.m:38
2014-06-06 16:43:28.593 Manicuriousv2[2261:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Database Failed to open'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x018d61e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x016558e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x018d6048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x012354de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   Manicuriousv2                       0x00002293 -[ViewController openDB] + 339
    5   Manicuriousv2                       0x00002307 -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 55
    6   UIKit                               0x0043433d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    7   UIKit                               0x004345d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x0045f509 -[UINavigationController rotatingSnapshotViewForWindow:] + 52
    9   UIKit                               0x007a6e3c -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 420
    10  UIKit                               0x0035bc22 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1495
    11  UIKit                               0x0035b646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    12  UIKit                               0x0035b518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    13  UIKit                               0x0035b5a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    14  UIKit                               0x0035a63a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    15  UIKit                               0x0035a59c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    16  UIKit                               0x0035b2f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    17  UIKit                               0x0035e8e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    18  UIKit                               0x00438b77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    19  UIKit                               0x00354474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
    20  UIKit                               0x003545ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    21  UIKit                               0x0035486b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    22  UIKit                               0x0dcda587 -[UIWindowAccessibility(SafeCategory) _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 77
    23  UIKit                               0x0035f3c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    24  UIKit                               0x0030fbc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
    25  UIKit                               0x00314667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    26  UIKit                               0x00328f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    27  UIKit                               0x00329555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    28  UIKit                               0x00316250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x038cbf02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x038cba0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x01851ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x018519db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0187c68c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0187b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0187b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    36  UIKit                               0x00313d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    37  UIKit                               0x00315f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    38  Manicuriousv2                       0x0000296d main + 141
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e1f701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Post complete error message.

Comment: I have added the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the exception message that you posted:

```
2014-06-06 16:43:28.590 Manicuriousv2[2261:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[ViewController openDB], /Users/jennifer/Desktop/Manicuriousv2/Manicuriousv2/ViewController.m:38
2014-06-06 16:43:28.593 Manicuriousv2[2261:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Database Failed to open'
```

*** First throw call stack:

The first line tells you where the problem was:

`-[ViewController openDB]`

The second line tells you what the error was:

`'Database Failed to open'`

So the problem lies with this part of your code:

```
-(void) openDB{
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &AppDB) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(AppDB);
        NSAssert(0,@"Database Failed to open");
    }else{

        NSLog(@"Database Opened!");
    }
}
```

At an educated guess, i'd say the issue was when you call the `sqlite3_open()` function.

The most likely failure reason for `sqlite3_open()` to fail is because the path you are using is read only.

Looking back over your code, your `-filePath` method is using `NSDocumentationDirectory` when it should probably be using `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. the error was with "NSDocumentDirectory" like waht you said it should be "NSDocumentDirectory".